# Java - How to decide the class hierarchies?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm recently studying the hierarchy design of how the Java inheritance works. But I'm not sure in which point I should start.

Given an example of calculating a binary expression, it has to use two classes `Literal` and `Binary`. But it suggests to give out the following sample outputs:

```
Literal a = new Literal(6);
Literal b = new Literal(12);

System.out.println(b);             //Prints out: 12.0
System.out.println(b.evaluate());  //Prints out: 12.0

Binary e = new Binary(b, a, Operation.DIVIDE);
System.out.println(e);             //Prints out: 12.0 / 6.0

Binary f = new Binary(e, a, Operation.PLUS);
System.out.println(f);             //Prints out: (12.0 / 6.0) + 6.0
System.out.println(f.evaluate());  //Prints out: 8.0

Binary g = new Binary(e, f, Operation.TIMES);
System.out.println(g.evaluate());  //Prints out: 16.0
```

*`Operation` is an enum defines four operations PLUS, MINUS, TIMES and DIVIDE

I have tried to design a class of `Literal` and another class `Binary` which extends from the class `Literal`... But I found that it might have something wrong for the following follow-up requirements of the outputs...:

```
Variable v = new Variable(“a“);
Expression n = new Binary(f, v, Operation.DIVIDE);
System.out.println(n);               //Prints out: ((12.0 / 6.0) + 6.0) / a

Environment x = new Environment();
x.addVariable(“a“, 4.0);             //Variable “a“ has a value 4.0 in x
System.out.println(n.evaluate());    //RuntimeException
System.out.println(n.evaluate(x));   //Prints out: 2.0 (8.0 / 4.0 = 2.0)
```

I found that the class `Binary` has to extends from `Expression` in order to meets the requirements... Actually am I wrong at the beginning for my design?

Comment: Why would `Binary` extend `Literal`? I'd expect them to both implement `Expression`.

Comment: Expression parsing is a perfect choice to apply a Composite design pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite

Comment: @JornVernee Because the variable `f` defined with an object of type `Literal`... Sorry... I may misunderstand with the concepts...

Comment: @null It says `Binary f = new Binary(...);` There also seems to be a typo in the second snippet, where `Expression n = new Expression(f, v, Operation.DIVIDE);` should probably have been: `Expression n = new Binary(f, v, Operation.DIVIDE);`

Comment: @JornVernee Oh! Yes it is a typo, corrected now... But The variable `f` defined as `Binary`, and inside the constructor it may have the type `Literal` or `Binary`... But I'm not sure how to fix it if it just considers the former requirements...??

Answer (score 1):

You should consider inheritance if you can describe objects of class `B` as *"is a"* of class `A`. Then class `B` should extend class `B`.

On the other hand direct inheritance between classes can cause some nasty problems so it is better to express the *"is a"* relationship via *interfaces* and have class `BImpl` a propery of class `A` where it delegates the inherited calls to:

```
interface A{
  void someMethod();
}
interface B extends A{
  void someOtherMethod();
}   

class C implements A {
  void someMethod(){}
}

class D implements B {
  private A a;
  D(A a){
    this.a=a;
  }

  void someMethod(){
    a.someMethod()
  }

  void someOtherMethod(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment the problem became clear:

> But The variable `f` defined as `Binary`, and inside the constructor it may have the type `Literal` or `Binary`

If both `Literal` and `Binary` extend `Expression`, then the constructor can take 2 `Expression` parameters, which means both `Literal` and `Binary` are acceptable:

```
interface Expression {...}
class Literal implements Expression {...}

class Binary implements Expression {

    ...
    public Binary(Expression lhs, Expression rhs, Operation op) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks that's what I think of for the follow up requirements. But the first stage (upper block) has only two classes, Binary and Literal, in the first requirement... The class Expression is for the second stage (lower block), as the requirements split into two parts...

Comment: @null, but nobody said you can't make more... right?